# Difference between Calendar.getInstance() and GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

Tags: java, calendar

Ever since it was first introduced to replace **Date** I have been using the static method **Calendar.getInstance()** to get a new **Calendar** object. I have never had a problem but I just wondered for some reason if it were better to use the **GregorianCalendar.getInstance()** method instead.

Is it possible my programs will run in some locale or some JVM somewhere where the superclass version will return an object class I wasn't expecting?  Has there ever been an implementation of **Calendar** *other than* **GregorianCalendar** that ever made it into wide use?

As I said I'm not having a problem at the moment but I am always looking to improve my practices.

Comment: In Thailand, the buddhist calendar is preferred and will be returned by `Calendar.getInstance()`. If you want to make sure that you get the gregorian calendar you should always use a constructor of that class, not the static factory method `getInstance()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Calendar could return a locale specific calendar.  From the source.

```
/**
 * Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The
 * <code>Calendar</code> returned is based on the current time
 * in the default time zone with the default
 * {@link Locale.Category#FORMAT FORMAT} locale.
 *
 * @return a Calendar.
 */
public static Calendar getInstance()
{
    return createCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
}

private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone zone,
                                       Locale aLocale)
{
    CalendarProvider provider =
        LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(CalendarProvider.class, aLocale)
                             .getCalendarProvider();
    if (provider != null) {
        try {
            return provider.getInstance(zone, aLocale);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // fall back to the default instantiation
        }
    }

    Calendar cal = null;

    if (aLocale.hasExtensions()) {
        String caltype = aLocale.getUnicodeLocaleType("ca");
        if (caltype != null) {
            switch (caltype) {
            case "buddhist":
            cal = new BuddhistCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            case "japanese":
                cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            case "gregory":
                cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cal == null) {
        // If no known calendar type is explicitly specified,
        // perform the traditional way to create a Calendar:
        // create a BuddhistCalendar for th_TH locale,
        // a JapaneseImperialCalendar for ja_JP_JP locale, or
        // a GregorianCalendar for any other locales.
        // NOTE: The language, country and variant strings are interned.
        if (aLocale.getLanguage() == "th" && aLocale.getCountry() == "TH") {
            cal = new BuddhistCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        } else if (aLocale.getVariant() == "JP" && aLocale.getLanguage() == "ja"
                   && aLocale.getCountry() == "JP") {
            cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        } else {
            cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        }
    }
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: BuddhistCalendar class is not available in Android. Can you help me from where to get this class and how to set the date and time?

Comment: @Pratik I have no idea.

Comment: @Pratik Android != Java, see also [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36773726/2491410) about non-gregorian calendars on Android